# Symfony3: pass value to Form EntityType be the default selected value

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form that should allow to add an item (**device**) to a category (**brand**). Below is a part of the controller that creates the form (the $brand thing doesn't work but I'll figure that out later). Below that is the code that creates my form.

I want my Select box (which is an entitytype of **Brand**, and shows all possible brands) to also show a default **selected** value, based on a variable passed down by the controller.

Two questions:

1. where can I pass this value down?
2. how can I set a default option for the EntityType select box? I expected it to be 'data' but even hard-coding a number there won't work.

This is the **controller** bit:

```
public function createDevice(Request $request, $brand) {
    $device = new Device();
    $form = $this->createForm(DeviceType::class, $device); // where do I pass the value of the default option?
    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

and the **type**:

```
class DeviceType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ->add('brand', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Brand',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'data' => '2' // does not set default value to second item!
```

Comment: Hi, in your code above you can't pass in `$brand` as an object via TWIG; but you could via the controller. Just trying to help you. If it was a brand ID, then you could use that in a querybuilder.

Comment: unsure what you mean? I'm not trying to pass objects to twig, I think. I'm a bit new to all of this :)

Comment: Hi there bluppfisk. You have the code with function: `createDevice(Request $request, $brand)`, and the variable `$brand`. Are you attempting to pass a brand object in to the function? If so, it needs to be an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set Brand into Device.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$brand = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Brand')->find(2);
$device = new Device();
$device->setBrand($brand);
```